# How many bytes can I fit into a QR code, with low error correction?

Tags: data, mobile, character-encoding, qr-code

I need to fit at least 300 bytes (or much much more) into a QR code and think I can do this by mapping each byte into the associated ISO/IEC 8859-1 character located here.

Since each byte (1-255) will only have one character associated with it, I can [test the utility of the idea with this demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/IGoT)  (the Email link has the dense QR I'm referring to)

Since I know that camera resolution plays a factor here, among other things I'm unaware of, I'd like to get a sense of how many individual characters I can put into a QR code before running into issues.  Any sizing, or resolution tips would be helpful.

The other assumption I have is that a QR reader can read every ISO/IEC 8859-1 character and pass it to my app

Comment: `300K` Do you mean KB or Kb?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner 10 arrays, each consisting of 32 bytes each.

Comment: Ok, but 10 arrays, with 32 bytes per array means there will be 320 bytes in total.

Comment: Put a nice short url in the QR code, and have your app download the necessary data from there.

Answer (score 17):

A QR Code has a version range from 1 to 40.  This information tells about how much data is stored within it.  [Version 40](http://www.qrcode.com/en/about/version.html) has 177 rows and 177 columns (in some decimation called 'modules') for 31,329 pixels.  It should be immediately clear at this point that this is the hypothetical maximum that doesn't take into account the error correcting or any of the other infrastructure of the QR code itself.

Once error correcting, infrastructure (the fixed patterns, for amount of error correction, targeting, frequency, mask patterns and such) and minimal error correcting get added, this is maxes out at 23,648 bits (2956 bytes - high level error correcting on version for is 10,208 bits 1276 bytes).

A version 40 barcode with 1276 bytes of data:

[image: Version 40, L ECC]

Once you get into the high capacity barcode area, you get into [color](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/hccb/about.aspx) 2d barcodes.  The back and white barcode technology tends to max out fairly quickly (data matrix can only hold 2,335 alphanumeric characters (not bytes)).

To go beyond the size limitations of version 40 in a QR code, one can used the [Structured Append](http://www.onbarcode.com/qr_code/#gsappend) (encoding mode 0011), though a quick search of various QR code reading libraries suggests that it is not something that any of them support.

A not uncommon approach for an alternative is instead to store a tag of data in the barcode which then references an online resource that has the full information.  Note that this works poorly in offline situations.

---

For dealing with much smaller chunks of data (300 bytes), 2400 bits of data can fit into a low error correcting version 11 QR code (it has 2592 bits of data to use for 321 bytes)

[image: Version 11, L ECC]

At this point, with lots more data space between version 11 and version 40, there are a number of encoding options if there are difficulties of getting the `byte[]` out of the data.  One could encode it in the alphanumeric character set that QR code allows (44 characters designed for web addresses - 11 bits for 2 characters in versions 10-26), or numeric (12 bits for 3 digits in versions 10-26) as the two easiest ones to work with.

Comment: My thinking was that 1 byte = one ISO/IEC 8859-1 character.  The wiki says this was a design spec in the ISO.  Are not all characters permitted (e.g. non printable) for QR, or their readers?

Comment: You've got 23,648 *bits* to work with.  How you encode that is up to you.  But thats the total number of bits on a version 40 with low error correcting.

Comment: Maybe the source of my confusion is that the only way to interact with the Kendo version of a QT generator is to send UTF8 or ISO/IEC 8859-1 data to it.  Binary isn't an option.. hence my question about non printable chars.

Comment: Different libraries may support different abilities.  For example, zxing has an [open issue](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/issues/28) for 'encoding of byte[]', so they probably can't do it that way either.  Others seem to suggest just using string ([thonky](http://www.thonky.com/qr-code-tutorial/byte-mode-encoding/)) and playing with those bits as UTF8.  Its not standard.  And you still only have 23k bits of data space.

Answer (score 2):

Putting too many bytes into a QR-code is not a good idea. The generated QR-code will be big and difficult to manage and read.

A better strategy is to link the data into an URL and turn the URL into a QR-code; there is no limit on the URL linked resource. You can put images, SVG, html, text file...

If your QR-code needs to represent structured information (e.g metadata), you can put an XML document at that URL.

There are some services that do this for you, for instance: [metaqrcode.com](https://www.metaqrcode.com/)

This strategy has some pros and cons:
pro :

- you can change data without reprint qrcode
- no big QR-codes
- smaller QR-code are easier to read

cons :

- you need an internet connection to read data

Comment: QR  code unable to be optized needs to be solve.. There are lots of use cases needing this extra storage capacity in offline situations and security